# Alfresco Default permission for actions

Tags: java, alfresco

I'm exploring alfresco action tag.

Following action tag does not specify permission

```
     <action id="document-copy-to" type="javascript" label="actions.document.copy-to">
        <param name="function">onActionCopyTo</param>
        <evaluator negate="true">evaluator.doclib.action.isLocked</evaluator>
     </action>
```

But following action tag specify the permission

```
     <action id="document-move-to" type="javascript" label="actions.document.move-to">
        <param name="function">onActionMoveTo</param>
        <permissions>
           <permission allow="true">Delete</permission>
        </permissions>
        <evaluator negate="true">evaluator.doclib.action.isLocked</evaluator>
     </action>
```

My Question is that what is the default permission if no permission is specify.
Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `permissions` section specify constraints on when to show the action depending on the actual permissions on the item. If you don't specify any `permission` then the action will be visible no matter of the current permissions on the node.